# Ubuntu software-center : Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt, software-installation, software-updates

Package software-center not found on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I tried to Install it via terminal, But ended up with below error :

```
ravip@LP204:~$ sudo apt-get install software-center
[sudo] password for ravip: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 software-center : Depends: software-center-aptdaemon-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-gi but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-gi-cairo but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon (>= 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: oneconf (>= 0.2.6) but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: software-properties-gtk but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: sessioninstaller but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

All `Depends` & `Recommends` Packages are already installed & at newest version.

How can I resolve ?

Comment: Since this is quite weird, can you also show how you tell that (at least one of) the Depends packages it complains about is installed (and at newest version).  Not because I think you're wrong, but sometimes that sort of thing can help to think of a suggestion.

Comment: @sourcejedi well, I have individually `sudo apt-get install <packageName>` executed and checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go To [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/index.php) :

1. Select Country
2. Select Release
3. Select Ubuntu Branches
4. Select Ubuntu Updates
5. Click `Generate`
6. Run Curl Command Given after List Generated

Run Following Commands :

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install software-center
```